# Another table for batch or not

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, inventory

SKU table have following attributes

```
SKU(id, name/description, batch, type, category, price)
```

**ID+Batch**  uses to define particular item.

Why uses batch attribute or what is this. 
Batch changes when price of an item changes. So in the eye of normalization suggest me is it necessary to record information about a batch in another table named batch

```
sku(id, name/description, batch, type, category ,price)
batch(sku_id, batch, price)
```

when price of an item change first go to batch table create new row include new batch and their price and then map this to  sku table.

Comment: You may want to have `date` in `Batch` table. If you do use `Batch` table then you need to remove price from `SKU` table.

Comment: yes Sir its good ides if batch table create then price will be remove from sku table. thanks